# Subquery not in performance question

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, subquery

I have this slow query

```
select * from table1 where id NOT IN ( select id from table2 )
```

Would this be faster by doing something like (not sure if this is possible):

```
select * from table1 where id not in ( select id from table2 where id = table1.id )
```

Or:

```
select * from table1 where table1.id NOT EXIST( select id from table2 where table2.id = table1.id )
```

Or:

```
select * from table1
left join table2 on table2.id = table1.id
WHERE table2.id is null
```

Or do something else? Like break it up into two queries ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question is - are the field(s) in the comparison nullable (meaning, can the column value be NULL)?

### If they're nullable...

...in MySQL the `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` perform better - see [this link](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/).

### If they are *NOT* nullable...

... `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` performs better - see [this link](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/).

Comment: Interesting, so the ids are not nullable so I should rewrite the query to use the left join and use is null ... thanks!

Comment: @Mark Steudel: You're welcome, but be aware that on any other database - `NOT IN` and `NOT EXIST` perform better than `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`

Comment: So this only happens on mysql dbs? Funny .. why is that?

Comment: @Mark Steudel: Because they aren't based on the same codebase

Answer (score 1):

```
select table1.* from table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE table2.id IS NULL
```

The object being to get rid of NOT IN